# Cheap, quiet (single-board?) Linux computer to act as a Borg backup target

Tags: quiet-computing, backup

With the demise of Crashplan for Linux I need a system for backing up my home desktop.

**My intent is to run a local backup server** to guard against things like hard drive crashes and then use offsite storage to mitigate the risk of fire/flood/meteor.

I plan to use [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/) because it will work with the [offsite storage provider](https://www.rsync.net/products/attic.html) I've chosen and because it's supposedly simple to run a Borg server on a linux OS.  I looked first at the Raspberry Pi 3 but found reports that the network and hard drive interfaces were too slow to be viable.

**No-Compromise Requirements:**

- Very quiet. Ideally no fans. I don't know where I'm going to put it but if it ends up in my bedroom I don't want to hear it.
- Reliable and fit for purpose (Cheap hardware is nice but my backups have to be there when I need them)
- My overall budget is $200.  If it's a single-board computer I will also need to buy a hard drive.  If there's an all-in-one product with hard drive storage included I can go up to $200.
- Must run Linux and have the horsepower to run Borg Server (but from what I've read if it can run Linux it can run Borg)
- Requires minimal hardware skill to set up. I'm not a hardware hacker. Plugging stuff in is about as far as my skill extends.

**Nice-to-have:**

- Small form factor

**Research I've already done:**
*in no particular order*

- [OrangePi Plus2](http://www.orangepi.org/index.html) (negative reviews, however that was 2 years ago)
- [PrimeSystems Core 2](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7625/9913) (concerned about noise, size)
- [ODROID-XU4](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/odroid-xu4) (expensive!)

Comment: Hi HardwareRecs!  I have plenty of experience on the network but this is my first question here.  Please let me know if you need more information or my question can be improved.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at some cheap used/refurbished fan-less computers.